# Linq-SQL error on Silverlight project

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

Below is my code using LINQ to SQL,on execution I get an error msg saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".I've joined 3 tables Users,UsersinRoles and Roles.Userinroles is the bridge table.I use join to retrive datas from 2 tables using bridge table i get the Object reference error.

```
 public class Users : CollectionFactoryBase
{
    public Users()
    {
        this.Summary = "Collection of Users";
    }
    public override Collection MakeCollection(CollectionRequestContext context)
    {
        UsersDataContext m_dataContext = new UsersDataContext();

        const int maxItems_c = 150;
        try
        {
           // string sessionvalue = HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionKey"] as string;

            var Users = from p in m_dataContext.aspnet_Users
                        join t in m_dataContext.aspnet_UsersInRoles on
                        p.UserId equals t.UserId
                        join r in m_dataContext.aspnet_Roles on
                        t.RoleId equals r.RoleId 

                        select new
                        {
                            UserName = p.UserName,
                            UserId   = p.UserId,
                            RoleId   = r.RoleId,
                            RoleName = r.RoleName,
                           userid = t.UserId,
                           roleid = t.RoleId


                        };


            Collection collection = new Collection();
            collection.Name = "Users";
            foreach (var user in Users.Take(maxItems_c) )
            {
                collection.AddItem(user.UserName, user.RoleName, null, null, null, null, null);
            }
            return collection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return ErrorCollection.FromException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: On build no error,on execution it opens up with this error but no line is specifically shown

Comment: Let Visual Studio break when an exception is thrown, it will be clear in a minute what causes the exception. My bet is that your `Collection` class is not kosher. What kind of weak types class is that anyway? Is a .net generic collection not better?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that last statement should be first one?

Comment: I had the last statement in the same place but with simple query it worked,after changing my query with join it's showing error.

Comment: I don't think that you show real code and as such we can't give you right answer except obvious one - you are trying to use something that wasn't initialized yet.

Comment: I'm using silverlight Pivot Viewer to show my collections from the database using LinQ-SQL.This is my real code for doing my collections.i need to show datas from multiple tables and that's what i've done as collection.additem where i get the datas from 2 table and make a collection and show in pivot viewer.This is my cs file.below is my full code

Comment: How about append .GetQuery() after each DBSet referenced in a query?